# Hair Particles Disappearing into Mesh

Tags: particles, edit-mode, hair

I am trying to comb the hair on a bust I made however the hair particles keep disappearing into the mesh.

I added a large amount of hairs to show the issue in the images below.

Before combing:

[image]

After combing:

[image]

After combing a large amount of hairs disappear leaving bald spots. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If you hit it with the puff brush with a low strength does it come back?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not from the outside. I went into the mesh and noticed that for some reason, after i've combed from the outside, some hair particles go into the mesh. when i go into object mode, the children hairs grow on the inside of the mesh. Is there a way to fix this? Maybe a constraint so the hairs don't disappear into the mesh?